# How do I detect change Sveltekit state

Tags: state, svelte, sveltekit

I am trying to add a class to an element in one component (nav) when an animation in a different component  (logo) ends. In my `$lib/Logo.svelte` file I have the following code:

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import { isLogoAnimationEnded } from './stores';

    onMount(() => {
        const body = document.querySelector('body');
        const h1 = document.querySelector('.name');

        h1?.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
            isLogoAnimationEnded.update((n) => (n = true));
            console.log($isLogoAnimationEnded);
            body?.classList.add('shake');
        });

        return () => {
            h1?.removeEventListener('animationend', () => {
                isLogoAnimationEnded.set(false);
                body?.classList.remove('shake');
            });
        };
    });
</script>

<div class="logo-wrapper">
    <h1 class="name">Tim Smith</h1>
    <p class="title">Full Stack Web Engineer</p>
</div>

<style>
  ...
</style>
```

My

store is defined in `$lib/stores.js`:

```
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

export const isLogoAnimationEnded = writable(false);
```

What I am trying to do is listen for a change in `isLogoAnimationEnded` in `$lib/Nav.svelte` and add a class to `nav` when `isLogoAnimationEnded` becomes `true`.

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import { isLogoAnimationEnded } from './stores';

    let nav;

    onMount(() => {
        nav = document.querySelector('nav');
        console.log('nav', nav);
    });

    if ($isLogoAnimationEnded) {
        nav?.classList.add('fly-down');
    }
</script>

<div class="nav-wrapper">
    <nav aria-label="Main">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="/projects">Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>

<style>
  ...
</style>
```

My current setup does not work.  Please help.

Comment: I have tried `isLogoAnimationEnded.subscribe()` that did not work either

Comment: Please use `bind:this={el}` and then `el.addEventListener` instead of querying DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below is only going to run once

```
if ($isLogoAnimationEnded) {
    nav?.classList.add('fly-down');
}
```

So I would delete it and write the class attribute on nav element like this:

```
<nav class={$isLogoAnimationEnded ? "fly-down" : ""} aria-label="Main">
```

This also gets rid of the onMount, nav variable and querySelector

Comment: Or `class:fly-down={$isLogoAnimationEnded}` https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-class-name